# What happens if the Russians decide to nuke the Kola borehole?

Tags: nuclear-physics, earth, geophysics, earthquake

I recently came across research on the [Kola Superdeep Borehole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kola_Superdeep_Borehole) in Russia. It's one of the world's deepest at 12 km (7.5 mi) down. If someone decided to hoist a nuclear weapon all the way down and set it off, what is the effects and can it be felt worldwide? Is there any simulation package that can help model this?

Comment: A very small earthquake?

Comment: This might be a question better suited to the [Earth Science sister site](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/). @dmckee if you agree, could you move it - or do I need to drop a flag?

Comment: @Floris there seems to be very little support for the idea that the question is off topic here. (But in general, if you think something is off topic, yes, you should flag. Don't _just_ ping a mod.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Kola borehole seems impressively deep, but compared to the thickness of the crust it is but a scratch. There's nothing special about the rock at a depth of 12km (except that it's hot - 180ºC!). Setting off a nuclear blast at the bottom of the borehole would be little different to any [underground nuclear test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underground_nuclear_weapons_testing). The seismic waves might propagate a bit farther than in a usual underground nuclear test, but that's all.